# Is there a way to get a list of widget ids from a SAC (Sap Analytics Cloud) Story page and store them into a vector or array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sac

I am new to JavaScript language.

I have a simple SAC Story that only has one page. This page contains some widgets, with widget Ids, such as: `Chart_01, Chart_02..., Chart_04, and Table_01, ... , Table_03`.

I want to write a JavaScript code that would collect the widget ids and store them into a vector or array.

I tried with the code that ChatGPT suggested:

```
// Create an empty array to hold the widget IDs
var widgetIds = ArrayUtils.create(Type.string);

// Select all widgets by their class and loop through them
document.querySelectorAll('.widget-class').forEach(widget => {
    // Add the widget's ID to the array
    widgetIds.push(widget.id);
});

// Log the result to see the collected IDs
console.log(widgetIds);
```

I find this code conceptualy logical, however SAC does not recognise the code snippet bellow the comment `// Select all widgets by their class and loop through them`

Is there a way to loop over widgets on the page and get their ids and store them into an array?

Thanks